# Wordpress - Memberpress Rest API v2 - POST/Create Transaction always return 403 Error

Tags: wordpress

I'm having some trouble with Wordpress REST API v2 and Memberpress,
what I am actually trying to do is to create a transaction using REST API and using BASIC authentication.

I've tried it using POSTMAN and it worked, but, when I apply on my web app, it always return a 403 error.

here is a snippet of the POST method

```js
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://localhost:8080/gmm_web/wp-json/mp/v1/transactions",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "authorization": "Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "postman-token": "806df233-f68c-09d6-9610-7894bedb1ea5"
  },
  "processData": false,
  "data": "{\n\t\"member\":\"80\",\n\t\"membership\":\"777\",\n\t\"gateway\":\"manual\",\n\t\"status\":\"complete\"\n}"
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Kinda stuck with this one and I need some help to solve this
Memberpress' documentation if I will be honest is crap, and its lacking a lot of info.

BTW, Ive installed WP-JSON and JSON API wordpress plugins and other plugins that can help with the basic authentication but none of them worked, even editing the htaccess doesn't work either.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rafael,

Try this instead:

```js
var credentials = btoa('myusername:mypassword');
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://example.com/wp-json/mp/v1/transactions",
  "method": "POST",
  "type": "json",
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + credentials);
  },
  //"headers": {
  //  "authorization": "Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  //  "content-type": "application/json",
  //  "cache-control": "no-cache",
  //  "postman-token": "806df233-f68c-09d6-9610-7894bedb1ea5"
  //},
  //"processData": false,
  "data": {
    member: 80,
    membership: 777,
    gateway: "manual",
    status: "complete"
  }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

I just tested this on my end and it seems to work.

Comment: that one worked! 
also noticed that i need to input the whole registered email address to the "username" and not just the username

thanks!